# Sequelize.js AWS RDS unknown database despite passing valid database identifier to configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to AWS RDS database from my code:

```
        const {
            DATABASE_HOSTNAME,
            DATABASE_BASENAME, // ches
            DATABASE_USERNAME,
            DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        } = process.env;

        this.sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE_BASENAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, {
            dialect: 'mysql',
            host: DATABASE_HOSTNAME,
        });
```

[image]

This is my AWS RDS database. However when I run my code I'm getting error:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
errno: 1049,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'ches'"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is empty "DB name" field in instance configuration source of problems?

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the problem. If you create a RDS instance without a default database, you have to create the database manually after. This is done via `CREATE DATABASE` in mysql.

Comment: I don't understand, this is already instance of mysql database. It is listed in RDS > Databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it can be seen that there is **no default DB created**.

```
DB Name: 
  -
```

By default, when you setup your RDS, it **does not create a database** for you. Instead you have a **DB instance**, which is listed under `RDS->Databases`.

When you setup your RDS you can use [Additional configuration section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateDBInstance.html) to provide a name of database to create, e.g. `ches`. Without this you have a DB instance without an actual database.

For **existing rds instances**, you can use `mysql` client to connect to the instance and create a database using standard `CREATE DATABASE ches;` as you would normally do in a mysql.